# How to align a div with an image horizontally within another div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having a lot of trouble creating a button in css.  Here is how it needs to work:

The button needs to have two sections, one for the call to action text, and the other with a right facing arrow.  This button needs to be dynamic, in the sense that it will be used in a content management system so it needs to expand it's height.

The right arrow needs to be lined up vertically with the text in the middle, however I cannot seem to achieve this.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="assetbuttonWrap">
  <div class="assetbuttonText"><a href="#" class="assetbuttonText">Click here to download the whitepaper</a></div><div class="assetbuttonIcon"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" width="8" height="12" alt="arrow"></div></div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
.assetbuttonWrap {
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
    margin-top:12px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    display:table;
}
.assetbuttonWrap:hover {
    background-color: #B6B6B6;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a.assetbuttonText:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #666;
}

.assetbuttonText {
    color: #737373;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 19px;
    max-width: 93%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.assetbuttonIcon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:10%;
}
```

I have attached an image as well, to see how it should look.

[CSS BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDhrZ.png)

[RIGHT ARROW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxy1A.png)

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Looks aligned to me. I added a margin and `display: table-cell` to the icon div... this any better? doesn't change much https://jsfiddle.net/tfcvenfq/1/

Comment: This actually is better, works great!  Thank you!

Comment: ok cool, wasn't sure since it didn't change much. Went ahead and submitted as an answer. If that solves the issue, you can click the check by the answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `display: table` on the parent, you want the direct children to be `display: table-cell` if you want them to work well and use the `vertical-align` property as a table would.

Added `display: table-cell` to `.assetbuttonIcon` and gave that element a padding to separate the text from the icon.

```css
.assetbuttonWrap {
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  display: table;
}

.assetbuttonWrap:hover {
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.assetbuttonText:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.assetbuttonText {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 19px;
  max-width: 93%;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.assetbuttonIcon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 10%;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="assetbuttonWrap">
  <div class="assetbuttonText"><a href="#" class="assetbuttonText">Click here to download the whitepaper</a></div>
  <div class="assetbuttonIcon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxy1A.png" width="8" height="12" alt="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing much you need to do. simply remove all the vertical-align property from all the css section. add vertical-align: middle .assetbuttonIcon img{ } img class. check the snippet below and here is a [livefiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5t4bdjw/1/)

```css
.assetbuttonWrap {
border: none;
padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
margin-top:12px;
height:100%;
background-color: #dddddd;
display:table;
}
.assetbuttonWrap:hover {
    background-color: #B6B6B6;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a.assetbuttonText:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #666;
}

.assetbuttonText {
    color: #737373;

    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 19px;
    max-width: 93%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
 
    display: table-cell;
}
.assetbuttonIcon {

    display:inline-block;
    max-width:10%;
}
.assetbuttonIcon img{
  vertical-align:middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="assetbuttonWrap">
 <div class="assetbuttonText"><a href="#" class="assetbuttonText">Click here to download the whitepaper</a></div>
  <div class="assetbuttonIcon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxy1A.png" width="8" height="12" alt="arrow"></div>
</div>
```